# Does a non-measurable set always contain a bounded non-measurable subset?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

This question might be easy but I lack the proper intuition of non-measurable sets.

The only example of a non-measurable set I can think of is the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Let $N$ be non-measurable, and $S_n = N \cap [-n,n]$. If $S_n$ was measurable for each $n$ then $S_n$ increases as a set to $N$ so $N$ would be measurable, a contradiction. Therefore for some $N$, $N \cap [-n,n]$ is non-measurable, which does the trick.

Comment: It seems that your construction relies on $N$ being bounded. That is $N \cap [-n, n] = N$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$. But what if the $N$ is not bounded?

Comment: No, I do not assume that $N$ is bounded. $N$ can be any non-measurable set. I've said that for some $n$, $N \cap [-n,n]$ is non-measurable. That is a subset of $N$ which is bounded and non-measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write down explicitly what is meant in @Teresa Lisbon's comment.

Let $S$ be an unbounded non-measurable set.
For $n\ge 1$ call $$S_n=S \cap [-n; n]$$
Argue by contradiction that all the $S_n$ are measurable. Then their union is measurable.
However
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S \cap [-n, n] = S \cap \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n, n] = S \cap \Bbb R = S$$
Hence $S$ is measaurable, contradicting our assumptions.

This means that some $S_n$ is not measurable. And clearly $S_n \subseteq S$ is bounded.